# Getting owner/creator information for a list using Sharepoint REST API

Tags: rest, sharepoint

Using the Sharepoint REST API, I am able to get "Author" (which I take as owner/creator info) information for both Files and Folders.  For Files, I can simply expand the "Author" element and get Title and UserId information.  For Folders, I have to use the "AuthorId" field from expanding "ListItemAllFields" to make a subsequent REST call to resolve the Title and UserId information by Id (I don't like this extra step either but I haven't found a way to get that info for Folders with a single GET).  However, for the base Lists and their associated "RootFolder"s, I do not get Author information, even if I expand the RootFolder's ListItemAllFields.  Is there a way to get the owner\creator information for at least the Document Library Lists where my Folders and Files reside?  I expected that expanding the RootFolder's ListItemAllFields would give me the "AuthorId" like it does for the sub-folders that have been created in the Document Library but all I get for this: .../_api/Web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('docLibraryRootFolderServerRelativeUrl')/ListItemAllFields, is:

```
{
    "d": {
        "ListItemAllFields": null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ListItemAllFields` property returns **associated** `List Item` with `File` or `Folder` objects.

For List object

REST query:

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(listtitle)/ListItemAllFields
```

returns nothing since `List` object is not associated with List Item object.

---

In order to retrieve `Author` property for `List` object you could utilize the following approach. The solution is to  *extract Author property from List  XML schema*.

The following method is used to return all available properties for `List` object:

```
function getListProperties(listTitle) {
   var listEndpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/SchemaXml";
   return getJson(listEndpointUrl).then(
          function(data){
              var schemaXml = data.d.SchemaXml;
              return schemaXml2Json(schemaXml);     
          });     
}
```

where

```
function getJson(url) 
{
    return $.ajax({       
       url: url,   
       type: "GET",  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: { 
          "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
       }
    });
}

function schemaXml2Json(schemaXml)
{ 
    var jsonObject = {};
    var schemaXmlDoc = $.parseXML(schemaXml);
    $(schemaXmlDoc).find('List').each(function() {
      $.each(this.attributes, function(i, attr){
           jsonObject[attr.name] = attr.value;
      });
    });
    return jsonObject;
}
```

**Usage**

How to get `Author` property for `List` object:

```
getListProperties('Discussion Board')
.done(function(properties)
{
    console.log('List created by: ' + properties.Author);
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Please follow [this post](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/11/09/an-alternative-way-of-getting-client-object-properties-using-sharepoint-rest-and-csom-apis/) for a more details.

Comment: Thanks Vadim, I'll have to give that a try.  My code is written in Java and I request JSON for my responses.  Will requesting the "schemaXml" endpoint with `"Accept": application/json;odata=verbose` give me a JSON response or would I have to get the XML and convert it to JSON as in your example.

Comment: Thomas, good question. Unfortunately requesting "schemaXml" endpoint will return a xml string and that's the reason why i am using schemaXml2Json. But I hope that converting xml string into json object could be done also easily in Java